# negative number when bitshifting

Tags: vb.net, integer, long-integer, bit-shift

Okay so I have 4 values(A, R, G, B) and im trying to make them into a decimal.

```
public function MergeABGR(A, R, G, B)
Return (A << 24) + (R << 16) + (G << 8) + B
end function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
msgbox(MergeABGR(dim a = 255, dim r = 255, dim g = 0, dim b = 255))
End Sub
```

The result im getting from this is: -65282.

I should be getting: 4294902015

Anyone know why this is happening??

```
Dim Decimal as Long = 4294902015
Dim outA as integer = SplitA(Decimal, OutA)
Dim outR as integer = SplitR(Decimal, OutR)
Dim outG as integer = SplitG(Decimal, OutG)
Dim outB as integer = SplitB(Decimal, OutB)


Public Function SplitR(ABGR, ByRef R)

    R = ABGR And &HFF
    Return R
End Function
Public Function SplitG(ABGR, ByRef G)

    G = ABGR >> 8 And &HFF
    Return G
End Function

Public Function SplitB(ABGR, ByRef B)

    B = ABGR >> 16 And &HFF
    Return B
End Function

Public Function SplitA(ABGR, ByRef A)

    A = ABGR >> 24 And &HFF
    Return A
End Function
```

After all this, these are the results I get
    outA = 255
    outR = 255
    outG = 0
    outB = 255

Comment: If you are working with colors you can extract the ARGB values directly.

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code.  Your functions do not specify any return types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, turn on [`Option Strict`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)(see also: [what's an option strict and explicit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/whats-an-option-strict-and-explicit)), so you have to define a type for everything.  It'll be worth it in the long run.

Now that we have to create types for everything, your function can look like this:

```
Public Function MergeABGR(A as Byte, R as Byte, G as Byte, B as Byte) as UInt32
    Return (Convert.ToUInt32(A) << 24) + (Convert.ToUInt32(R) << 16) + (Convert.ToUInt32(G) << 8) + B
End Function
```

Where we return an `UInt32`, and also convert the parameters to `UInt32`s, so that we don't overflow the maximum value of anything.  4294902015 is sufficiently large to not fit in a signed 32 bit integer, so we switch to an unsigned 32 bit integer to hold it instead.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you SOOOOOOOO MUCH hahaha :D